`xarray`: merging two `DataArray`s which have only one shared dimension results in a `Dataset` that lists other dimensions?
Some preliminary setup:
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

xr.set_options(display_style="text")

<xarray.core.options.set_options at 0x7f28242cf7d0>

Suppose that I have labels which are composed of two parts: first and second:
raw_labels = np.array(
    [["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["c", "a"]],
    dtype="<U1",
)
raw_labels

array([['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'a']], dtype='<U1')

I can make an xarray.DataArray easily enough to represent this raw information with informative tags:
label_metas = xr.DataArray(
    raw_labels,
    dims=("label", "parts"),
    coords={
        "label": ["-".join(x) for x in raw_labels],
        "parts": ["first", "second"],
    },
    name="meta",
)
label_metas

<xarray.DataArray 'meta' (label: 4, parts: 2)> Size: 32B
array([['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'a'],
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
Now suppose that I have additional information for a label: let's say it is some count information for simplicity.
raw_counts = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(label_metas))
raw_counts

array([17, 10, 97, 72])

label_counts = xr.DataArray(
    raw_counts,
    dims="label",
    coords={"label": label_metas.coords["label"]},
    name="count",
)
label_counts

<xarray.DataArray 'count' (label: 4)> Size: 32B
array([17, 10, 97, 72])
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
How do I combine these clearly related xr.DataArrays? From what I understand: by using xr.Datasets.
label_info = xr.merge([label_metas, label_counts])
label_info

<xarray.Dataset> Size: 160B
Dimensions:  (label: 4, parts: 2)
Coordinates:
  * label    (label) <U3 48B 'a-c' 'b-a' 'a-b' 'c-a'
  * parts    (parts) <U6 48B 'first' 'second'
Data variables:
    meta     (label, parts) <U1 32B 'a' 'c' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'a'
    count    (label) int64 32B 17 10 97 72
It is weird that as far as dimensions go, we have "label" and "parts", because the only shared dimension that exists between the xr.DataArrays in this xr.Dataset should be "label"?
How should one understand that the xr.Dataset has two dimensions "label" and "parts"?

The answer I wrote for this closely related question is equally applicable here.
